# How to know what is the Clearcase server view?

Tags: clearcase

I think that the Clearcase server is also used for hosting the view server, but how can I be sure?

`#cleartool hostinfo -long
Client: abcd123
Product: ClearCase 8.0.1.4
Operating system: AIX 1 7
Hardware type: 00C7D6164C00
Registry host: abcd123
Registry region: ggg
License host: abcd123.kalzam.razel.steria.ch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in "[Rational ClearCase server processes](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/c_intro_serverprocs.htm)", a `view_server` is a long-lived process that manages activity in a particular view.

So if you see any view_server process on a given host, then that host is a view server.
But that does not mean it is the only one, and any ClearCase client can also hosts its own view (if ClearCase was installed with a view server as part of its features)

---

See also [`cleartool lsstgloc`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsstgloc.htm) for listing registry information about server storage locations for views, VOBs, or both.

```
cleartool lsstgloc -view -host anHostname
```

If that returns something, then 'aHostname' is a view server.

---

If you have a view tag in mind, describe it to get its view storage path:

```
cleartool lsview -l -full -pro aViewTag
```

From that global path, you can get the view server hostname with:

```
cleartool lsstgloc -view -long -storage a/global/path

Type: View
Region: atria_r_d_unix
Storage Location uuid: 3988ccaa.412d11d4.a313.00:01:80:7c:c6:73
Global path: /net/peroxide/export/home/bert/stgloc_view1
Server host: peroxide
Server host path: /export/home/bert/stgloc_view1
```